# How to create clickable lines in android

Tags: java, android, canvas, graphics, event-handling

If I use the line :

> canvas.drawLine(stx,sty, spx,spy);

How can  I later detect with for example `MotionEvent` whether the line was touched or not?
Let's assume that the line is not straight.

I know there are things like `Rect` or `RectF` that can handle events but with those I can't draw slope lines.

Maybe someone could suggest me an alternative method to draw this lines so that the object used could handle the events...

---

Well after all night research it seems that the way to go is to switch from Canvas to OpenGL ES API.

### And yet another foul trail...

But after giving it a second though if have

> Line ( Point ( x1, y1 ), Point2 ( x2, y2))

Like a loving mother, `Math` comes with understanding and simple answare, with simple line of code we can determine wheather the event point is contained in `Line`:

> (x2 - x1)*(eventY - y1) = (y2 - y1)* (eventX - x1);

To simply blur the touch area we can add:

```
for(int i = -10; i<10;i++){
 for(int j=-10; j<10; j++){
  if((x2 - x1)*(eventY+i - y1) == (y2 - y1)* (eventX+j - x1))
   return true;}}
```

Comment: pleases put more effort into a nice presentation. Title should not have * simple * misspelling, it seems a bit unfair to us. and though I use "aint" as much as the next guy, I cringe to read it

Comment: I know this doesn't give you the code... sorry, welcome to the meta-world of http://stackoverflow.com hehe

Comment: i dont need the code , im looking at least for idea how to do smth like this.